# What next after 1 e4 e5 2 Nf3 Nc6 for the White tactical player?

Tags: opening, 1.e4

How should a tactical player as White play after 1 e4 e5 2 Nf3 Nc6?

The openings I am looking at are:

- Ruy Lopez
- Italian game
- Scotch game
- Three Knights

I am currently playing Scotch since it opens the centre early and I think it gives me more activity. Are there any other variations I should consider if I want activity and tactics?

Comment: You might be interested in looking into the Italian; for instance, it can lead to lines such as the Evans gambit and the fried liver attack which are very sharp and tactical.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the `Scotch Gambit`. 1. e4 e5 2. Nf3 Nc6 3. d4 exd4 4. Bc4! The game becomes very tactical. For example, if Black attempts to protect the pawn by playing 4. ... Bc5, 5. c3! is a very useful recourse. If Black takes this pawn, 6. Bf7+! is a tactic, after 6. ... Kxf7 7. Qd4+! Wins the piece back.

Example game (White player = Nakamura) https://lichess.org/Zny0pBLO#27